# Cannot start KDE in Fedora 22

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, lxde

I cannot load KDE, XFCE or any desktop environment other than GNOME in my Fedora 22 system. Every time I try `startkde` I get `$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to X server`. Tried all the solutions [here](https://nowardev.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/startkde-display-is-not-set-or-cannot-connect-to-the-x-server/), [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=112516) and [here](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/891) and it still doesn't work. How to fix this?

Comment: If you don't get a useful response here, you could always try the KDE forums. They are usually extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type in a shell

```
type X
```

and there's an error, you forgot to install `xorg-server`.

Check this too :

```
fgrep '(EE)' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```